# How to update forked repo as dependency during npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, npm

I have this project ***MyProject*** that uses a forked repo (***ForkedRepo***) as a dependency.

The thing is: When i make changes in the ***ForkedRepo*** i'm not able to npm install correctly in ***MyProject***

What i'm doing: After making changes in ***ForkedRepo***, i change its version in package.json and push to github

When i run npm install in ***MyProject*** , it's ignoring the ***ForkedRepo*** dependency and does not install the updated forked package

What's the correct way to make it work ?

In ***MyProject*** package.json i have the following

```
"dependencies": {
  "mydependency": "https://github.com/mycompany/forkedrepo.git"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify a branch of your forked repo. like this

```
git://github.com/<user>/<project>.git#<branch>
```

Comment: actually im already doing that. I'd like to update this repo automatically, without the need of always changing the package.json branch. Dont know if is possible.. tkz

Comment: @victorkurauchi You got any solutions?

Comment: try to `yarn upgrade --latest mydependency` or its equivalent in npm

Comment: Thank you @Bertuz! It worked perfectly. 
I don't understand why your comment is the only place on the internet that explains how to do it.